# Cargar "DOMContentLoaded" con React usando router de react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Actualmente estoy incursionando en el mundo del Front usando vite con react js para la creación de una pagina web y me encuentro en un problema, espero puedan ayudarme y de antemano muchas gracias.

De entrada estoy utilizando Vite con React Js para trabajar con la plantilla basada en boostrap y algunas personalizaciones de la misma.

Sé que puedo importarlas directamente pero es más trabajo migrar la plantilla que aprovechar las herramientas que me ofrece Vite.

En este orden de ideas, ya he logrado que cuando llamo el index me carguen los scripts, haciendo uso de un evento de escucha al cargar la página.

```js
/* Se llama desde el index y es donde se hace el llamado a cada una de las funciones
de animación y demás de la página.

Lo he hecho de esta manera, porque antes tenía el problema al cargarlo directamente
que los elementos no eran encontrados pues el js cargó antes que el dom,
independiente de donde lo situara. */
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      /* Creamos una etiqueta "<script>" */
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      /* El atributo "src" apunta al script que deseamos cargar */
      script.src = "assets/js/dom.js";
      /* Insertamos el script en el DOM (al final del <body>) */
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
```

Este proceso me funciona hasta el momento de maravilla.

El problema va en que he implementado "react-router-dom" para poder navegar por la página renderizando cada uno de los componentes según corresponda, pero pasa que cuando reutilizo un componente ya no tengo la funcionalidad que antes tenía.

Ejemplo:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKH9J.png)

Al dar clic a cada una de las categorías me filtra cuando la página es refrescada, pero como el Router de React no refresca la página al llegar nuevamente a esta sección, ya sea en el index o en su nuevo llamado en la otra página, pierde las funciones.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZGdG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Investigando en varios foros y también en la misma documentación [useEffect][1]

[1]: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html me he dado cuenta que debo cargar el script con el mismo componente, es decir, antes lo hacía todo un js llamado dom.js que cargaba todas las funcionalidades como el carrousel, slides, etc. Para este caso, en cada componente en puesto de manera independiente cada funcionalidad en su respetivo componente.

```
useEffect(() => {
    var glightbox = GLightbox({
        selector: '.glightbox'
    });
    
    let portfolionIsotope = document.querySelector('.portfolio-isotope');
    if (portfolionIsotope) {

        let portfolioFilter = portfolionIsotope.getAttribute('data-portfolio-filter') ? portfolionIsotope.getAttribute('data-portfolio-filter') : '*';
        let portfolioLayout = portfolionIsotope.getAttribute('data-portfolio-layout') ? portfolionIsotope.getAttribute('data-portfolio-layout') : 'masonry';
        let portfolioSort = portfolionIsotope.getAttribute('data-portfolio-sort') ? portfolionIsotope.getAttribute('data-portfolio-sort') : 'original-order';
        let portfolioIsotope = new Isotope(document.querySelector('.portfolio-container'), {
        itemSelector: '.portfolio-item',
        layoutMode: portfolioLayout,
        filter: portfolioFilter,
        sortBy: portfolioSort
        });

        let menuFilters = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-isotope .portfolio-flters li');
        menuFilters.forEach(function(el) {
        el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.querySelector('.portfolio-isotope .portfolio-flters .filter-active').classList.remove('filter-active');
            this.classList.add('filter-active');
            portfolioIsotope.arrange({
            filter: this.getAttribute('data-filter')
            });
            if (typeof aos_init === 'function') {
            aos_init();
            }
        }, false);
        });
    }            
});
```

Con esto ya he dado solución al problema que se venía presentando.
Espero pueda servirles a ustedes también.